# Kylo | Read Only Permission for Running Feeds

Tags: kylo

How do I give read only permission for Operation Manager in Kylo to logged in user ?

Permission Setting

[image]

Ops Manager View

[image]

Logged in user is able to Fail/Abandon running job.

Thanks
Shashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a UI bug and those buttons shouldn't be displayed if you don't have administrator privileges. I tried duplicating your issue and it seems those buttons don't work without the Administer Operations privilege. I get the following error message:

> An unexpected error occurred Access control violation: Not authorized to perform the action: Administer Operations

You can file a bug report to have the issue resolved in a future release: https://kylo-io.atlassian.net/

Comment: Thanks for logging the JIRA. This issue has been fixed now. The UI will not show the `FAIL` and `ABANDON` buttons if `Administer Operations` permission is not granted.